# Timestamp to UTC ISO 8601 date

Tags: python, date, datetime, utc, iso8601

This

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1501545600).isoformat()
```

should output `2017-08-01T00:00:00Z` or `2017-08-01T00:00:00` but I get

```
2017-08-01T02:00:00
```

instead, probably because of local timezone.

How to make `.isoformat()` output an UTC time instead, i.e. `2017-08-01T00:00:00`?

If possible I'd like to use only `datetime`, and no other third party library like `arrow` or `dateutils`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `utcfromtimestamp()` rather than `fromtimestamp()`. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp):

> Return the UTC datetime corresponding to the POSIX timestamp, with tzinfo None.

With no tzinfo specified in `fromtimestamp()`:

> If optional argument tz is None or not specified, the timestamp is converted to the platform’s local date and time, and the returned datetime object is naive.

Which doesn't seem to be what you want.

Comment: This is the correct answer, more info [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be `datetime.utcfromtimestamp()` then?

From python docs:

> classmethod datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp)¶
>   Return the UTC datetime corresponding to the POSIX timestamp,
>   with tzinfo None. This may raise ValueError, if the timestamp is out
>   of the range of values supported by the platform C gmtime() function.
>   It’s common for this to be restricted to years in 1970 through 2038.